# FormControlName must be used with a parent FormGroup directive when FormGroup is passed to child component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular9, angular12

**Parent Component**

```
  <form [formGroup]="User">
    
    <app-radioButton [group]="user"></app-radiobuton>
    
    </form>
```

**In Radio Component html**

```
<mat-radio-button  [formControlName]="name" > <mat-radio-button>
```

in .ts of Radio component

```
export class RadioComponent{
@Input() group: FormGroup;
}
```

Giving error as above. Not sure what wrong am i doing.

Answer (score 16):

The reason why its failing its because Angular is waiting for FormGroupDirective on any of parent - child elements. So:

In child component please declare:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  viewProviders: [
   { 
     provide: ControlContainer, 
     useExisting: FormGroupDirective 
   }
 ]
})
```

OR

You can use formControl in the child component:

```
<mat-radio-button [formControl]="name"><mat-radio-button>
```

Comment: Can you make first way with `ControlContainer` example on stackblitz, please? I can't make it works.

Comment: Here you go Anton
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfctab?file=app/ang-form.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is `[formGroup]="User"` and you pass to child component `[group]="user"`. Why there is different data provided: `User` and `user`?

If you want to use your `FormGroup` the way as you done, - just make your form group wrapping for a child control in the child component too:

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="group">
  <mat-radio-button [formControlName]="name"><mat-radio-button>
</ng-container>
```

The other way is to make a more proper component structure:

```
<form [formGroup]="User">
  <app-radioButton [formControlName]="name"></app-radiobuton>
</form>
```

And inject control in the child component. You can check how to do it [here](https://medium.com/p/e5bb3bb6710)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind it that you are using a form control field which is out side of the form tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).